# Shut Python webserver down after a defined number of accesses/downloads

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-services, webserver, limit

I'm trying to find a way, to shut down a Python webserver after a certain number of accesses/downloads. I simply run a Python webserver with the following code:

```
import http.server, socketserver

port = 8800
handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", port), handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I want to stop serving, after a certain number of downloads/file-accesses have been reached.

A single file access is usually logged as:

```
192.168.0.1- - [01/Jan/1970 00:00:00] "GET /file.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Is there a way to directly parse the logs of the webserver and react accordingly?

For instance, if a certain number of occurrences of `"GET .* 200 -`have been reached, stop serving.

Comment: Well, you can subclass `http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` and make the derived class do whatever you want with the requests.

Comment: Hi @SaAtomic, do you need _inner-python_ solution? or could be an external one, let's say, in unix-like bash scripting?

Comment: You could extend the server to do what you want.

Comment: @RafaelAguilar I'd prefer Python, but I'm open for suggestions. How would you accomplish this in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count the number of requests and exit the http server after a specific amount is reached. This is a very basic example how it could work:

```
import http.server, socketserver
import sys

def shutdown(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        cls = args[0]

        if cls.count > 5:
            print ("shutting down server")
            sys.exit(0) 
        else:
            return fn(*args,**kw)
    return wrapper


class myHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @shutdown
    def do_GET(self, *args, **kwargs):
        myHandler.count += 1
        super().do_GET(*args, **kwargs)

    @shutdown
    def do_POST(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.count += 1
        super().do_POST(*args, **kwargs)


port = 8800
handler = myHandler
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", port), handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: needs some fine-tuning, as the shutdown doesn't work right now - but I can definitely use this as for my project! thank you very much!

Comment: The exit function does not work, as it simply raises a `SystemExit` exception and doesn't know what to do with it